# How to solve the system of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

How can I solve this system of equations? (without using any software of course)

$$\ e^{-y} \cos(x)= \frac{5 \pm3}{4}  \quad\text{and}\quad\ e^{-y} \sin(x)=0$$

Comment: Note that $e^{-y} > 0$ for all $y$.  Thus $e^{-y}\sin(x)=0$ only when $\sin(x)=0$.

Comment: therefore I'll know all the values that x can take? and with Alex's hits the y values. right?

Comment: Yes; once you find the solution values you need to double-check that $\cos x>0$ for your solutions (because squaring may give you extraneous solutions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** square each equation and add them together. This will eliminate $x$ because $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1. $